# Merge [email] and [email-client]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Half of the questions tagged with [email-client](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email-client) are [also tagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email+email-client) with [email](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email) (62 / 130) .

> **[About](https://superuser.com/tags/email/info) [email](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email) (tag wiki):**
>
> ***Questions about email clients***, mail transfer agents
>   and email software configuration. Questions about webmail are
>   off-topic.

I don't think we need both [email](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email) and [email-client](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email-client), since they're basically the same. Both of them refer to email clients and not webmail, which is off-topic.

If [email](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email) refers only to the mails themselves and not email clients such as Gmail, Outlook and Thunderbird then we have a lot of retagging to do.

I suggest removing [email-client](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email-client) (making it a synonym of [email](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email)) and using [email](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email)[name-of-the-email-client](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/name-of-the-email-client) instead (e.g [email](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email)[gmail](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gmail) for Gmail emails related questions).

Comment: Even in the worst case, the retagging needed here pales before the ongoing nuking of the SO homework tag where ~7k questions have been manually retagged or deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The [top-voted question tagged email only](https://superuser.com/q/235937/35237) makes a good example of a question that has nothing to do with [email-client](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email-client), so removing [email](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email) should be out of question. On the other hand, [email-client](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email-client) seems to be rather useless  - either a question can be tagged by the specific client, e.g. [thunderbird](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird), or it is so general that it could be tagged [email](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email) as well. I am however not quite sure how I should actually tag [my own recent question](https://superuser.com/q/512242/35237) to indicate that it's about the OS setting of which email client to use...